# If constraints in SystemVerilog

Tags: system-verilog, verification, random-number, testbench

I have a class of sequence item with rand variables:

```
class my_seq_item extends uvm_sequence_item;
rand bit a, b, c, d;
```

I want to generate a random bit for 'd' only if 'b' and 'c' are 0.
How do I write a constraint for this?

Comment: What should bit 'd' be otherwise? Or stay the same?

Comment: bit 'd' should be 0 otherwise. If b and c are 0, bit d should be 1

Answer (score 2):

```
constraint my_constraint { if (b==0 && c==0) d==1; else d==0;}
```